# Explicit example of a compact manifold of dimension $>2$ with strictly negative sectional curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I am looking for examples of compact manifold of dimension $>2$ with strictly negative sectional curvature (for dimension 2 it is well-known). Can anybody please help?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_3-manifold

Comment: What about any $n$ in general?

Comment: There are explicit examples in dimension 4, maybe 5. However, in general dimension I am not even sure what "explicit" means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for examples in relatively small dimensions $>3$ then consider reading  [this paper](https://people.math.osu.edu/davis.12/old_papers/4-mfld.pdf)  by M.Davis and [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9907139v1.pdf) subsequent paper.   Examples exist in all dimensions but they are much less constructive. The second linked paper in principle explains how to produce them, but getting explicit torsion-free finite-index subgroups becomes increasingly difficult as dimension grows.  You may want to ask yourself: What are known "explicit" examples of compact manifolds of dimension, say, 9999, and you will find that they are all derived from a handful of constructions involving: (1) fiber bundles, (2) homogeneous spaces of some compact Lie groups, (3) some low-dimensional examples, (4) some quotients by finite groups. Here by "explicit" I mean that you have some known handle decomposition with a list of handles and attaching maps which fits into a couple of pages.