# Example of compact riemannian manifolds with seccional curvature negative

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I need a example of a riemannian compact manifold with seccional curvature negative. The idea is take hyperbolic space and a suitable group that acts proper, free and discontinuously and with quotient compact. But i don't know very much  about groups acting in hyperbolic space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073239/explicit-example-of-a-compact-manifold-of-dimension-2-with-strictly-negative?rq=1