# Existence of compact space forms of negative curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

> Do there exist *compact* Riemannian manifolds of constant negative sectional curvature in all dimensions $\geq2$?

The two-dimensional case is well-known. For higher dimensions, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073239/explicit-example-of-a-compact-manifold-of-dimension-2-with-strictly-negative) asks for explicit examples, and it turns out that the construction could be very difficult. But what if I only ask for existence? Is there an easy way to show that that $\mathbb{H}^n$ admits a compact quotient manifold for all $n\geq2$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a theorem of Borel that all linear real semisimple Lie groups have a cocompact Lattice, you can check that the isometries of hyperbolic space satisfy this.

Comment: @NickL Is the quotient necessarily a manifold then?

Comment: @Colescu: Selberg proved that every finitely generated matrix group contains a torsion-free subgroup of finite index. Hence, after passing to a finite index subgroup, the quotient will be a manifold in your setting.